# POST JSON Data using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json

Why is my code not sending the data to server ? It does display the data into the console but doesn't seem to be sending anything.

```
document.querySelector("form").addEventListener("submit", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            var formData = {
            "name": e.target.elements.name.value,
            "author": e.target.elements.author.value,
            "link": e.target.elements.link.value
            }

            var req = new XMLHttpRequest();

            req.open("POST", "http://localhost/javascript-web-srv/post_form.php", true);
            req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

            req.send(formData);

            formData = JSON.stringify(formData);

            console.log(formData);

        });
```

Comment: `req.send(JSON.stringify(formData));`

Comment: Why stringify? Why not just send the data?

Comment: @JeremyThille because you are sending an array

Comment: So? What's wrong with sending an array?

Comment: @query — `formData` is a plain object, not an array.

Comment: @JeremyThille — The `send` method expects to be passed a string. If you implicitly convert an object to a string you get `"[object Object]"`. That isn't the data you want to send. Also: **the question explicitly asks to send JSON**. A plain object isn't JSON.

Comment: Ah, that's plain JS, I didn't know `send` expected a string. I'm too used to jQuery's `ajax` and Angular's `http`, I never use plain JS. And yes, OP asks to send JSON data, but most people don't seem to know the difference between a JSON and a JS object, so I don't think this was a specific requirement :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> req.send(formData);
> formData = JSON.stringify(formData);
> ```

Your code is backwards.

In order to send JSON, you need to convert your object to JSON and *then* send it.

```
formData = JSON.stringify(formData);
req.send(formData);
```